# Java - too fast to recognize?

Tags: java, time

**Complete code:** https://github.com/Sheldor5/JavaGPP (see tests for both options)

I have some weird behaviors with command patterns and loops (counting down until the actual command action should be executed):

What I am trying to achieve:

I am currently developing a game and in this game I want to place a "bomb" and this "bomb" should explode in e.g. 2 seconds. I am doing this with command patterns where one type of command substracts the`delta` from the left `timeLeft` variable until the `timeLeft` variable is <= zero --> so if the 2 seconds have passed the explosion should take place. This is not working if I execute the command in a while loop because the bomb explodes after +2.2 seconds and not after 2 (and some nanos). If I add a `Thread.sleep(1)` in the loop the time is accurate enough for me so I can say the calculation of the `delta` is done rigth.

**Option 1:**

```
// infinite loop: execute all commmands in the executor (only one command for now)
while (true) {
    commandExecutor.executeCommands();
}

// the only one command in the executor gets called everytime
public static final long NANOS = 1000000000;

private long timeLeft = NANOS;
private long start;

public Command() {
    this.start = System.nanoTime();
}

public execute(final long delta) {
    this.timeLeft -= delta;
    if (this.timeLeft <= 0) {
        final long time = System.nanoTime() - this.start;
        System.out.println(String.format("Successfully executed Command with ID '%s' in %dns (%dns)", this.getID(), time, this.timeLeft));
        this.timeLeft += NANOS;
    }
}
```

**Expected Output (1 second interval):**

> Successfully executed Command with ID '1' in 1000000454ns (-454ns)
>
> Successfully executed Command with ID '1' in 1000000695ns (-695ns)
>
> Successfully executed Command with ID '1' in 1000000549ns (-549ns)
>
> Successfully executed Command with ID '1' in 1000000003ns (-3ns)

**Actual Output ():**

> Successfully executed Command with ID '1' in 1267062727ns (-266ns)
>
> Successfully executed Command with ID '1' in 1350811695ns (-165ns)
>
> Successfully executed Command with ID '1' in 1352353549ns (-145ns)
>
> Successfully executed Command with ID '1' in 1263098003ns (-75ns)

But if I add a `Thread.sleep()` into the loop the actual output is much more accurate:

**Option 2:**

```
while (true) {
    commandExecutor.executeCommands();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Acceptable Output:**

> Successfully executed Command4 with ID '40' in 1000015964ns (-47338ns)
>
> Successfully executed Command4 with ID '40' in 1001095472ns (-316309ns)
>
> Successfully executed Command4 with ID '40' in 1000039457ns (-224116ns)
>
> Successfully executed Command4 with ID '40' in 1001043666ns (-662982ns)

Can someone explain this to me? Is the loop too fast? Is something so fast that it can't recognize the actual value of the variable and it wrongly sees it as greater than zero? Why there are so big differences and from where are those ~0.2 seconds?

Comment: It's hard to follow what you're actually trying to do. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I'll update the question

Comment: Why do you only set `this.start` *after* using in in a formula already? Is that supposed to be the start time of the next command?

Comment: nope this part of code was left from other experiments ;)

Comment: Where does the `delta` come from?

Comment: If I understand you correctly you're asking why `final long time = System.nanoTime() - this.start;` yields a vastly different value than `this.timeLeft -= delta;` (`+NANOS`?). Is that correct? If so we'd have to see how you're calling that code and how you calculate the delta. Overall your code seems a bit odd: calculating times twice using different methods, (re)setting `start` _after_ using it (for the _next_ command if I understood correctly) etc.

Comment: What is the GC activity during your test?  Add -verbose:gc to your experiment.

Comment: Besides your code the ultimate goal seems clear to me. I'd probably use one timer thread that checks whether a command should be executed (most probably by iterating over a command list sorted by time) and then starts a new thread for the command or hands it over to an executor's task pool. If you execute all commands on the same thread they'd delay others that should run concurrently.

Comment: Is `execute` getting invoked a lot? Like, almost continuously? (That part should be in the code you show us, BTW.) If so, you may have cumulative rounding error.

Comment: How would `this.timeLeft - delta` have anything to do with `System.nanoTime() - this.start`? Are you trying to make a function decrease a value by how much it takes said function to do said task? Looks like an attempt at a self-fulfilling prophecy to me o.0

Comment: I would also try to get output without String.format :)

Comment: @ErickG.Hagstrom yes `execute()` is invoked alot (while(true) --> execute()) @Siguza `this.timeLeft -= delta` should be the countdown (decreasing ``this.timeLeft` by the delta until `this.timeLeft` is zero) and `System.nanoTime() - this.start` is just to see if the time is really 2 seconds which it isn't ....

Comment: @Thomas the rest of the code is a simple Command Pattern like you can find it on every tutorial page on google ^^ see update.

Comment: @ErickG.Hagstrom see linked github

Comment: @Gimby I fully understand this but i think its easier if the people who want to help simply can use the whole code instead of copy-pasting together the code pieces I would post here.

Comment: @Gimby yes I read the MVCE but I can't find the part where it states that I shouldn't link to external pages? Also the linked github project only consists of everything needed to reproduce the problem and nothing more (expect for 3 other command classes)

Comment: I'm just removing my comments, this isn't going anywhere productive.

Answer (score 0):

Originally I thought this was a concurrency issue but I don't think it is because your custom executors and commands don't spawn any new threads. Instead I think that youre just instrumenting your time too much. Your code is basically just looping and calling `System.nanotime()`. The problem with the approach of using your `delta` variable is that you aren't taking into account the time involved in calling `System.nantime ()`. But youre calling it a lot. I think that using a timer task would be be preferable but if you want to do this yourself try something like the following:

```
long start = System.nanotime ();
long inTwoSecs = start + 2000000000L;
while (true) {
    long now = System.nanotime ();
    if (now >= inTwoSecs) {
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay but then the command is executed in now + 2 seconds and not in 2 seconds play time (pausing and resuming) ^^ But I think I need to find another way to handle this.

Comment: @Pali You could do something similar, but have a method. getGameTime, and update that appropriately. The while loop in your example is just going to spin for some amount of time, but it also isn't related to your game time.

Comment: @matt no because I am handling the nanos in the future with a delta - which is related to the game time ^^

Comment: @Pali no to what? a) I am only going on what you have pasted here. b) *public static final long NANOS = 1000000000;* So I don't know how you are 'handling' that so it is related to the game time.

Comment: @matt `public execute(final long delta)` where `delta` is the time in nanos between the last execution and the current execution while the last execution time is being updated properly on pausing/resuming the game. And if I decrease `private long timeLeft = NANOS = 1000000000L;` by this delta, `timeLeft` is the time left until the actual event in the game - not in the real world ^^

Comment: @Pali I see, so delta is your game time. So why do you think the difference in actual time should be related to the game time? Eg. System.nanoTime()-start is the wall clock time.